# Swift 4.1 returns Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Just updated Xcode and my code to swift 4.1 and now i get this error on line one of the code below - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeea880ff8)

It worked just fine before the update and this error message doesnt help me much, could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    if let settingsData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "settings"),
        let settings = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ExploreSettings.self, from: settingsData) {
        self.init(settings: settings)
    }
```

When printing UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "settings") it returns nil but when checking if it is nil it just throw the same error

```
if UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "settings") == nil { 
   print("nil")
}
```

Comment: Don't `try?`, `catch` the error, the message could be helpful.

Comment: Use `do` and `catch` to decode your json. catch will throw error.

Comment: The error happens before that

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint and get the stack trace. Actually this code cannot crash due to unwrapping `nil`.

Comment: are you using some background thread for execution?